# MLflow artifacts on S3 but not in UI

Tags: amazon-s3, mlflow

I'm running mlflow on my local machine and logging everything through a remote tracking server with my artifacts going to an S3 bucket.  I've confirmed that they are present in S3 after a run but when I look at the UI the artifacts section is completely blank.  There's no error, just empty space.  [image]
Any idea why this is?  I've included a picture from the UI.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I think the MLFlow UI properly connects to the place where the artifacts are (otherwise, it would just say "No Artifacts Recorded". It just does not display them... did you solve it?

Comment: @Requin Not yet.  I put this to the side while I was working out other issues but I'm starting to look into it again.  I'll post if I find an answer.

Comment: I solved this problem; the MLFlow server had the wrong artifact location in my case. This connection pointed to a non-existent address.

Comment: I'm glad that you have it working now.  I'm not accessing the UI by calling mlflow server so that issue shouldn't affect me since the location is specified by my remote tracking server and is correct since the artifacts are making it to S3.  I wonder if the extra layer of abstraction (having a remote tracking server) is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should see the 500 response in your artifacts request to the MLflow tracking server e.g. by clicking on the model of interest page (in the browser console). The UI service wouldnt know the location (since you set that to be an S3 bucket) and tries to load the defaults.

You need to specify the  `--artifacts-destination s3://yourPathToArtifacts` argument to your `mlflow server` command. Also, when running the server in your environment dont forget to supply some common AWS credentials provider(s) (such as AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY env variables) as well as the MLFLOW_S3_ENDPOINT_URL env variable to point to your S3 endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Could you please clarify what you mean by the S3 endpoint url?  Do you mean the literal URL for the S3 bucket: https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/etc....?  I'm trying this out but I seem to still have problems.  When I go into the UI for my bucket to look for the URL both they copy URL and copy URI buttons are greyed out.

Comment: This is only if you're running S3 in a custom environment where you need to specify where it resides. F.e., if you have a locally emulated S3 setup, you can pass the env var to be `MLFLOW_S3_ENDPOINT_URL=http://localhost:4566`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with mlflow running on an ec2 instance. I logged into the server and noticed that it was overloaded and no disk space was left. I deleted a few temp files and the mlflow UI started displaying the files again. It seems like mlflow stores tons of tmp files, but that is a separate issue.

Comment: Glad that it started working for you.  When you say you were running mlflow on ec2, do you mean that EVERYTHING is on the same EC2 instance or just the tracking server?

Comment: I was running just the tracking server on ec2. Models were running on different server(s)